# Ubuntu 18.04 Live squash boot with PXE on multiple machines

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, boot, pxe-boot

I have set up a **WDS PXE server** that is able to install Windows and Linux operating systems in may different ways.

The server is also able to live boot **Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop squash files** (official & my own custom made).
Each squash has its own NFS share on the server.

But when I need to live boot a machine with an Ubuntu 18.04 squash, **I am unable to boot another live machine using the same squash file** unless I turn off the previous one, or else the previous machine simply freezes.

Sometimes I even need to live boot 3 machines, and I am not a fond of creating more shares and cloning squash files, as it is not a real scaleable solution.

Might be a chance that some of the files are getting locked? Seems weird as live boot should only read files from the share.

Here is my menu stanza for the live boot:

```
LABEL Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop live boot
MENU LABEL - Live boot with ubuntu 18.04
kernel /external/live/casper/vmlinuz
append boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=x.x.x.x:/lb vga=normal ip=::::::dhcp initrd=/external/live/casper/initrd --
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use NFS and use CIFS instead
you will also need an additional initrd INITRD_N11.2.4.GZ; see how Serva does it here:

[https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html)